# How to decrypt data with a pem file?

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa

I have the following:

- A pair of keys generated with openssl [in the manner described here](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt).  The keys are called `rsa_1024_priv.pem` and `rsa_1024_pub.pem`.
- An encrypted message, `file.enc`, which was [generate through this test page I created](https://gist.github.com/MKorostoff/d298ae98e2672926fabc6e1ffe0a981e).

How can I decrypt `file.enc` from the command line?  What specific command do I need to give?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
base64 -D file.enc > binary_messge.bin
openssl rsautl -decrypt -in binary_message.bin -out decrypted_message.txt -inkey rsa_1024_priv.pem
```

The problem was that the encrypted data needed to be base64 decoded before I could decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Decrypt with the private key...
          var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
          decrypt.setPrivateKey($('#privkey').val());
          var uncrypted = decrypt.decrypt(encrypted);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply justin, but as I stated in my question, I'm looking to do this from the command line.